# Specifying a branch in git fetch

Tags: git, branch, fetch

What does the branch parameter mean when issuing

```
git fetch <remote_repo> <branch>
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branch parameter is the name of the branch in your  that you are going to fetch.

See an example in the git docs:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html

`git fetch origin +pu:pu maint:tmp`

> This updates (or creates, as necessary) branches pu and tmp in the local repository by fetching from the branches (respectively) pu and maint from the remote repository.
>
> The pu branch will be updated even if it is does not fast-forward, because it is prefixed with a plus sign; tmp will not be.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  So if branch parameter is simply "somebranch", then that implies "somebranch" sits somewhere in the remote repo... if it doesn't exist, then nothing will be fetched?

Comment: That's right. If the branch doesn't exist on the remote git will respond with something like "fatal: Couldn't find remote ref somebranch"

Answer (score 0):

You should [read the manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) for questions like this. To answer your question, "git fetch < remote_repo>" will fetch all the of the remote branches you have configured for that repo. This is controlled by the entry for that repo in .git/config. Adding "< branch>" fetches only one branch, which might not even be one that you are remote tracking.